# Running javascript on pinned tabs in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I want to run some javascript on pages opened in pinned tabs in firefox, specifically I want to modify the dom of web pages which are loaded in pinned tabs. How do I do that with firefox addon api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Firefox [tabs API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs). Any [Tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab) has a "pinned" property that can be read from the background page.

For example, you may do it in this way:

Make isTabPinned request bridge in your background script, which will get the tab property and send it to the content script.

**bg.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.request == "isTabPinned") {
        sendResponse(sender.tab.pinned);
    }
});
```

In content-script send the request to the background script bridge to get the tab pin status and modify the DOM if the tab is pinned.

**cs.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ request: "isTabPinned" }, tabPinned => {
    if(tabPinned){
        //.. modify your DOM here
    }
});
```

Load the content script to pages you need to check (or to any pages as it in the example) and background script. Give the "tabs" and "activeTab" permissions to your script.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Pin Detector",
    "version": "0.1",

    "background": {
      "scripts": ["bg.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["cs.js"]
      }
    ],

    "permissions": ["tabs","activeTab"]
}
```

Comment: Rather than have your content script(s) injected with a `content_scripts` entry in your manifest.josn, it would be much better to programmatically inject the content script only into the pinned tabs, using `tabs.executeScript()`. The way you're doing it burdens *every page the user ever goes to* with loading and running your content script. A user, potentially, has thousands of tabs open, and might visit multiple pages with each tab. It's not reasonable for you to run code in each page when only a few might be pinned. Specific example: I have 6 pinned tabs and just under 1,800 tabs.

Comment: Hm, yes, you're right, your scheme might has a much better performance than my one :) The goal of my answer is to show the easiest way to solve the problem. But the other side, your decision will require to query and loop all 1800 tabs all the time, beacuse I haven't found any event triggered on tab is pinned, but user may pin/unpin the tab in runtime.

Comment: The `tabs.onUpdated()` event fires when a tab is pinned/unpinned and provides which tab has been pinned. It also fires when the URL for each tab changes (and tells you if that tab is pinned), which you'd also need to listen for . If your content script *must* be as close to `document_start` as possible, then it gets a bit tricky and more complex. However, given that for your scheme your content script waits to do anything until it gets information from the background script (i.e. if pinned), it will already be delayed from `document_start` by two inter-process communication times.

Comment: Thanx! I will write PoC on weekends and will attach it to my answer if you are OK :)

Comment: I'm fine/happy with you adding that way of doing it to your answer, or changing your answer to using that approach. I do feel that approach should be in an answer here, as it uses less resources, potentially considerably fewer resources, than running a content script on every page. If you don't add it, I'll put writing up an answer with that approach on the list of things I should do. That list is a bit long, so I'm unsure when/if I'd get to it.